# Branch.io: What will happen if MAU exceeds from license limit?

Tags: branch.io

We are sending email to users with branch.io generated link.
Once user clicks/taps we are opening our app/web.

Our concern is if MAU are exceeded from licensed users and any users taps/clicks emailed link what will happen? 
Is App/Web will open via link tap/click?

Ex: Under free account 10K MAU are allowed. And 10001 user click/tap the link what will happen?

Answer (score 2):

You can find this defined on our pricing page located [here](https://branch.io/pricing/), which you may have already encountered. To be more specific, an MAU is any user who's been engaged with Branch in any fashion on your app or web experience.

Branch charges for premium solutions and services that integrate deep links into marketing tools that manage and provide insight into a variety of marketing channels. Core deep linking platform such as link click and redirection remains free regardless of your MAU.

Comment: Let me clarify: that means if you get 110k of organic traffic only, you will get $500 invoice from branch with 0 value provided. Though it's probably still a better value if you have more than 10k of paid traffic.